# C# calculating area and perimeter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, geometry

so im using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.
im trying to make a program that calculates area and perimeter.
i have 2 text boxes for length and width.
i have 2 readonly text boxes for area and perimeter.
so i put in the numbers for area and perimeter and i get the answers in the area and perimeter readonly boxes when i click the "calculate" button.
what's the code for this calculation?

Comment: For extra credit, see if you can wire up your program so that you don't need to click "calculate" and instead have it calculate anytime the values change! Also make sure you test these values: -1,0,1,NAN,Int.MAX,Int.MIN,A, null.

Answer (score 3):

Well that would be simple. Using basic geometrical formulas: *Area = height x width* and *Perimiter = (height + width) x 2*

Then simply do this:

```
int pmtr = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) * 2;
int area = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

textBox3.Text = pmtr.ToString();
textBox4.Text = area.ToString();
```

Also, you might want to look at [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to make the code a bit more stable and avoid exceptions on invalid values.