# calculating area and perimeter

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# calculating area and perimeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859882/c-calculating-area-and-perimeter)

so this is what it looks like:
http://img51.imageshack.us/i/ffffde.png/

i have to make it so that when i put the numbers in length and width and i press calculate, the numbers show up in the area and perimeter boxes.
can someone get me started for the "calcualte" button code?
and what do i need codes for textboxes 1 and 2?

Comment: This was not enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859882/c-calculating-area-and-perimeter/4859919#4859919

Answer (score 0):

To get started on the Calculate button code, double-click on the Calculate button in the designer.  This will create an empty Click event handler which you should then fill in as needed.  You can access the Text properties of the controls on the form within this event.